# Should we merge the tags "school" and "education"?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

The tags on [this question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/5593/what-should-i-consider-when-deciding-whether-to-homeschool-my-child) made me think about this.

- Is there any difference in meaning between the two words, or are they actually synonyms?
- If they are synonyms then which one should be the tag and which one the synonym?

Answer (score 2):

I see them as related, with some overlap, but distinct.

To me, [education](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) refers to anything related to teaching, whether it is classroom learning, homeschooling, social skills/manners, or helping a child pursue a particular topic that is of interest to them.  It covers everything directly related to the process of learning, both formal and informal.

I see [school](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/school) as referring to the specific structure of formalized education, with a focus more on the environment than the actual process of learning.

Questions on education would be "how do I teach my child the importance of proper grammar?" or "my child is having problems learning how to read; how do I help them?" or "when is it the right time to teach a child not to interrupt?".

Questions on school would be "I have a problem with a teacher; how do I address it?" or "how do you determine which is a better school environment between these choices?" or "my child is being bullied in class; how do I work with the staff to fix this?" or "what types of resources should I have on hand when setting up a classroom environment at home?"

Comment: Your differentiation makes sense. We should edit the tag descriptions to make it more evident. I'm going to take a stab at it some time.